# gnome super button doesn't search files

Tags: gnome, files, search, 16.10

In Unity, the key combination "Super+F" finds files by name (even partial name) with no trouble, but in gnome, pressing "super" and then searching works for applications and folders (among other things), but not for files.

I have changed the "Search" settings on "system settings" but that doesn't seem to do anything. ("Files" is marked, but it still won't find any files)

Am I missing something? Or alternatively, what is the key combination to search for files in Gnome?

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 with Gnome shell version 3.20.4

Comment: Every Desktop Enviroment has it's own different shortcuts. But what most have in common is the Super key.

Comment: With gnome the default gui in ubuntu again I am also sorely missing the ability to search for files by pressing the super key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GNOME 3 search bar with no results](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976172/gnome-3-search-bar-with-no-results)